# FFT window phase synchronizing

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft, phase

I'm not sure if you could help with this. Im currently devising a solution of demodulating a DPSK signal in C#. i have got sofar a working FFT with Phase detection BUT.

I now have an issue of aligning the window off the FFT to synchronise with each symbol transmitted on the audio stream - now i've done some manual testing and for a test transmission i rendered, i have symbols with a window width of 19 samples.

I do understand that DPSK is designed to avoid a reference signal for demodulating the input signal but FFT window alignment is still needed.

Now the problem is that because this will be potentially used on amatuer radio where transmission times are entirely random the alignment of each symbol will have to be determined. The transmission i rendered has a clock timing header of 1024 symbols but how can i be sure to get the alignment right?

For example the header is like:

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 etc etc

and the phase of the sine wave rendered from this bit stream would be 0, 90 0, 90, 0, 90 etc etc

how can i make sure that the receiver will determine the transmitted phase and not anything like 15, 105 ,15, 105, etc etc as this will also introduce spurious phase calulations from the fft detecting the higher frequency harmonics due to the jump in phase.

Comment: Why are you using an FFT for this ? It seems like overkill ?

Comment: FFT retrieves both frequency and phase in realtime. There is a potential for parallel DPSK transmissions in the 22.05Khz bandwidth

Comment: It still seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and I'm not even convinced it will work - you will have to make your FFT length equal to just one DPSK period *and* synchronize it somehow. This also means that you *can't* use it for multiple channels unless they are all at the same rate and are all synced to some master reference clock.

Comment: You might have better luck at http://dsp.stackexchange.com. And Paul R is right - FFT approaches require synchronizing to a master clock. OFDM uses this technique, but has a whole equalization/sync front end before the FFT.

Answer (score 0):

Using an FFT is overkill.  But since you are working with an overkill solution, why don't you just try all 19 possible window locations for your FFT?  Pick the FFT result with the least phase error from a legal signal, and use its location to feed a phase lock loop for the symbol timing.